# MariaDB partitionning last 3 month

Tags: mariadb, partition

First, I explain my problem:

This is a table that will contain approximately 5,000,000 record per year, these records will be kept at least 10 years (it is not yet defined). We talk about events of production machine. I generate a report + a dashbord for displaying various information relatively complex (average number of events per 10 minutes a month, graphics, ...) and also wants to see the records themselves. The data displayed will be in large majority of the last 2 months, viewing the rest of the data must always be possible but at a lower speed of access.

I work on MariaDB v10.1.12.

The idea was to make a partition on the last 3 months. I realize now that this is not so easy. I have not found any solution to this partition, in fact, it is impossible to make a partition based on a now() or other current_date() etc. directly or indirectly via another calculated column.

Do you have any ideas for me? Perhaps another solution than a partition.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you want to partition a table base on CONTINUOUS changing value?  I don't see why going through that kind of trouble. Partitioning table on fix monthly or quarter will fix in most usage condition.

Comment: Thanks, but this will generate "infinite" partitions. Is it ok? Is there no problem with that?

Comment: table partition is "best things since sliced bread". Please check my answer.  You need to read more about database partitioning topic and ask it if you have any doubt.

Comment: I understand the continuous partitioning by month or by quarter but if we want data, let's say from the 15 of Mars to the 15 of April, this mean data are in 2 different partitions, is it still efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend **`PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(...))`**  If you are only now breaking the table into partitions, I would recommend annual partitions for data before this year, then quarterly or monthly partitions henceforth.  Yes, that, in theory, leads to an infinite number of partitions, but I predict that you will revamp the data structure within a few years.

**20-50 partitions** is a good number.  More than that leads to inefficiencies due to the multitude of partitions; less than that leads to asking "why bother".

Use InnoDB.  Design the **`PRIMARY KEY`** carefully, since it may be useful as the primary index into the data.

Usually it is best to put the **date/timestamp column *last*** in any indexes.  Putting it first would be redundant since partition pruning comes first.

[*More on partitioning*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).

It sounds like a main purpose for the table is to summarize the data for graphing, etc.  In that case, it may be very beneficial to build and maintain "**Summary table(s)**" of counts and subtotals over selected time intervals.  100 rows get added up for a 10-minute interval?  If so, then the summary table based on 10-minute intervals would have 1/100th as many rows, and the queries would be *much* faster.  Plus, you could 'denormalize' the summary tables to make them even simpler.

[*More on Summary tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables).

It *might* be worth it to gather data for 10 minutes into a **staging table**, then summarize it into the summary table.  And also throw the raw data into the big table.

Or, if the summary tables have everything you need, you could **abandon the big table**.  Or, as a compromise, **keep 12 month's worth** of data (partitioned by month), and `DROP PARTITION` for older data.  Meanwhile, the summary tables can continue to grow (although they will be much smaller).

Answer (score 0):

Table partitioning is an advance features, it is not indexing, but rearrangement of tables data. So it is not "duplicate", indeed new data will stored according to the predefined partitioning range.

You must also specify month range criteria as usual. you MUST create index if those column are not used as partition range.  When you make a select, algorithm that associate with partition table will handle those merging(if required) in background. So you just treat partition exactly like your typical table.

For more details, please check [Mariadb paritioning overview](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/partitioning-overview/)

Comment: Thanks you, I will go with continuous partitioning. And I have indead indexed the column.

Comment: Nevertheless, depends on your data structure. if each rows are big, then you must consider denormalise.

Comment: No, the row is not big.

Comment: Also some reading of partition vs indexes.  Just use both. 
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45937/partitioning-vs-indexes